# Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module, on Mac M1

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor, nvm, sharp

I had been trying to resolve this issue and had tried running the app via rosetta terminal, but same issue persists. I tried installing the **sharp** package globally but that to did not help.
Here is a snippet of the error :-
[I think the issue is something related to Sharp package specific for the arm architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEfRt.png)

I was trying to setup a repo on my system locally and simply ran yarn dev. I expected the server to start but the same error keeps coming again and again .

Comment: was just able to install it on mine, can you try just `yarn add sharp` or `npm i sharp` alone and comment back the error you get

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to this conversation: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/pull/3514

Specifically "On an M1/M2 based machine, the dylib files provided by a globally-installed vips (via Homebrew or otherwise) will be ARM64, therefore we cannot use these when running Node.js under x64 emulation as there will be a runtime conflict."